# nginx redirects to subfolder for prettier links

Tags: php, redirect, nginx, vhosts, pydio

I have a question concerning nginx redirects / try_files:
I have a website (vhost managed by ISPConfig3) at www.XXXYYY.com
In the root directory there are folders, index.php and so on.
I want certain files in `www.XXXYYY.com/folder21/public/309273.php` to be accessible at `www.XXXYYY.com/309273` (to have prettier links).

However, everything I tried yet did either not work at all or the .php-files got downloaded instead of being processed by PHP-FPM…

This is the nginx vhost directive I'm currently trying out in ISPConfig3:

**This is being set by ISPConfig3:**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files @php;
    }

location @php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9026;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

**This is the part that is being added by me at the bottom of the vhost-file:**

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /folder21/public/$uri.php /index.php =404;
}

location /folder21/       { internal; }
location /folder21/public/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php;
}
```

Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: do you have a block that captures the php files ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks for pointing this out! I just added the php blocks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with for **pydio**:

```
location /conf/       { deny all; }
location /data/       { internal; }
location /data/public/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?$args;
    rewrite ^/data/public/([a-z0-9]+)-([a-z]+)$ /data/public/$1.php?lang=$2 last;
}
location ^~ /share/ {
    rewrite ^/share/(.*)$ /data/public/$1 last;
}
```

PHP-files in `/data/public` are now served through `/share` without the need of the .php-ending.
Files in the format of e.g. `/data/share/XYZ123-en` are being rewritten to`/data/share/XYZ-123.php?lang=en`.